# Conditional operator with same underlying class type

Tags: c++, c++14, conditional-operator, decltype

Should this program output 0 or 1? In my reading and understanding of the cited paragraphs from the C++14 standard, it should print 1, but both GCC and clang prints 0 (because the deduced type is `A const` instead of `A const&`):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A const& ra = std::move(a); // #1

    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(true ? ra : std::move(a)),
                              A const&>::value; // Prints 0
}
```

In this case, `ra` is a `A const` lvalue, and `std::move(a)` is a `A` xvalue, both of class-types. According to the standard about the conditional operator (emphasis mine), the result should be an `lvalue` of type `A const`, and thus the `decltype` result must be `A const&`:

> **[expr.cond]/3** Otherwise, if the second and third operand have different types and **either has (possibly cv-qualified) class
>   type**, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
>   attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other. The process for determining
>   whether an operand expression E1 of type T1 can be converted to match an operand expression E2 of type
>   T2 is defined as follows:
>
> — If **E2 is an lvalue**: E1 can be converted to match E2 if E1 can be implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the
>   type **“lvalue reference to T2”**, subject to the constraint that in the conversion the reference **must bind directly (8.5.3) to an lvalue**.
>
> [...]

In this case, **E2** is `ra`, which is a lvalue, and the other can be implicitely converted to **"lvalue reference to T2"**, as shown in line `// #1`. **"lvalue reference to T2"** is translated as `A const&`, so, `std::move(a)` binds directly to a lvalue of type `A const`, and after the conversion, both operands have same type and value category, and thus:

> **[expr.cond]/3** If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category [...].

So, the operator result should be an lvalue and the `decltype` result should be a reference, and thus the program should print 1.

Comment: this potentially affects the behavior of `std::common_type`, no? or at least, the default implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type

Comment: @ChrisBeck In this particular case no because the template parameters are first decayed.

Comment: @Peregring-lk You should **never** modify a question in a way that can invalidate other people comments (or answers).

Comment: It's ok, he should just mention what compilers do what in the question after he changes it imo. Comments are lightweight. Invalidating answers is bad though, should just ask a new question

Comment: There is no type deduction in this code. By "deduced type" I guess you actually refer to the common type of the second and third operand of the conditional operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is awkwardly worded. You should instead ask what the type and value category of the expression `true ? ra : std::move(a)` should be. The answer to that question is a prvalue of type `A const`. This subsequently means the program should print 0, as I think every compiler correctly does.

---

The rules for `?:` are fairly complex. In this case, we have two expressions of class type that we try to see if we can convert to each other, based on a limited subset of rules.

Attempting the conversion `ra` → `std::move(a)` fails. We first try with a  [target type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#3.2) is `A&&` which can't bind directly to `ra`. We then try the backup plan in [(3.3.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#3.3.1) since the two expressions have the same underlying class type, but our target expression is not at least as cv-qualified as the source expression, so this also fails.

Attempting the conversion `std::move(a)` → `ra` fails [(3.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#3.1) because we need to bind directly to an lvalue (we can bind an rvalue to a const lvalue reference, but here we are **required** to bind an lvalue). But, the [(3.3.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#3.3.1) backup succeeds because now the target type *is* at least as cv-qualified as the source.

Hence, we apply the conversion and we continue as if the second operand were an lvalue of type `A const` but the third operand is now a prvalue of type `A const` (instead of an xvalue of type `A`).

[(4)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#4) fails, because they're not of the same value category.

Hence, the [result is a prvalue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#5). And since they have the same type, [the result is of that type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.cond#6.1): `A const`.

Comment: @Barry What are the rules of "binding to lvalues"? The chapter about "reference" binding speaks about "references". What is the meaning of "binding directly to an lvalue"? I understand all of the steps except that one, which is the one that changes everything.

Comment: @Peregring-lk I don't understand the question. The wording has a requirement that we bind to an lvalue, but our other operand isn't an lvalue - it's an xvalue - so we can't do it.

Comment: @Barry Ahhh ok now I see. The requirement is over the **reference** (`T const` lvalue), and not the operand that must be binded (`T` xvalue). I was thinking the other way around.

Comment: @Barry How many "copies" are involved here? Two isn't? When creating an rvalue from the xvalue (which creates a temporary) by (3.3.1), and by (6.1) to create the final result, even if the first operand were `false` in my example.

Comment: @Peregring-lk The operations described in [expr.cond] don't actually happen, they just determine the resulting type. `b ? ra : std::move(a)` is either a copy (of `ra`) or a move (of `a`).

Comment: A const lvalue reference binds directly to xvalues. The whole expr.cond/3 doesn't apply as the operands are of same type but different value category.

Comment: @RustyX They're different types, one is `A const` and the other is `A`.